# How can I restore Firefox's old "keyhole style" back/forward buttons in the latest version?

Tags: firefox, browser

When upgrading to Firefox 15 from 12 (on Windows 7), I noticed that the back/fwd buttons are much smaller and vastly different in style. Is there any way to restore the old, larger "keyhole style" back button in v15?

Screenshot of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heh, the new ones look like Chrome. Anyways, [this plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cstbb/) will change your navigation buttons back to the old style.

Comment: Thank you very much! :) I can't comment on the similarity to Chrome (I've steered clear of it because there has been so much controversy regarding Google's examination or tracking of the URLs you visit etc.) but I can say that I like the older Firefox look better!

Comment: I've accepted the fact that, if you're on the internet, someone, somewhere, is tracking what you're doing. I just like Chrome because it lets me sync my tabs between all my devices. Glad I could help you out here :)

Answer (score 3):

This particular feature/design has not changed with Firefox 15.

1. Right click on the toolbar, click `Customise`.
2. Make sure the back/forward buttons are right next to the address bar. There should not be anything else in that space. Rearrange any extra icons, or remove them by dragging into the `Customise Toolbar` box.

   [[image: Screenshot]
   <sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBBdR.png)
3. Click `Done`. The buttons should merge with the address bar.

   [[image: Screenshot]
   <sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfr2C.png)

Note that the forward button is hidden by default when there is no page to go forward to. This behaviour started in Firefox 11. [SaintWacko's answer](https://superuser.com/a/470820/117590) is probably your best option if you want to unhide it at all times, or detach it from the address bar.

Comment: I'll always prefer native solutions over added components. Nice solution!

Comment: Huh. I didn't have anything between the buttons and the bar, but by dragging them away and then back, they did indeed merge. Cool.

Answer (score 1):

You will also see a difference in B/F button styles if you check/uncheck the 'Use Small Icons' setting in Customize Toolbar options.